# How to access member controls in a WPF derived UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I have a Windows phone based control and want to derive other Windows phone `UserControl`s from it.

When I put the derivation code in and try to access other controls from the derived class, I get an error:

```
The name 'LocationConsent_CheckBox' does not exist in the current context
<path>\project\RML\RML\CtrlLocServ.xaml.cs
```

Base `UserControl` xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RML.CtrlBase"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Base `UserControl` code behind:

```
namespace RML
{
    public partial class CtrlBase : UserControl
    {
        public CtrlBase()
        {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    LayoutRoot.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

Derived `UserControl` xaml:
(Notice I have changed the name of the grid to LayoutRoot2 instead of LayoutRoot.)

```
<src:CtrlBase x:Class="CtrlLocServ"
             xmlns:src="clr-namespace:RML"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot2">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="LocationConsent_CheckBox" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</src:CtrlBase>
```

Derived `UserControl`, code behind:

```
namespace RML
{
    public partial class CtrlLocServ : CtrlBase
    {
        public CtrlLocServ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LocationConsent_CheckBox.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This still gives me the above error though.

Here is the generated file:

```
#pragma checksum "..\..\CtrlLocationService.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "D56B477B354FB03C45E5F49343F67196"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18063
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.TextFormatting;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Shell;
namespace RML {


/// <summary>
/// CtrlLocationService
/// </summary>
public partial class CtrlLocationService : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {

    private bool _contentLoaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// InitializeComponent
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/RML;component/ctrllocationservice.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

        #line 1 "..\..\CtrlLocationService.xaml"
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);

        #line default
        #line hidden
    }

        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Design", "CA1033:InterfaceMethodsShouldBeCallableByChildTypes")]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Maintainability", "CA1502:AvoidExcessiveComplexity")]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")]
        void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
            this._contentLoaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where your `LocationConsent_Checkbox` is declared.

Comment: in the Derived user control Xaml ...

Comment: Ok, I think that I see your problem. You can't use a XAML file if you want to extend a control. That means that you can't define sections of XAML to use in this way. Instead, just define XAML in `DataTemplate`s and apply them to `ContentControl`s to display them.

Comment: Sorry... I don't get what you mean - can you give an example?

Comment: Read through the [`Data Templating Overview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN and you'll find out.

Comment: I tried the code (with minor modifications, so that it compiles), and I can access LocationConsent_Checkbox from CtrlLocationService

Comment: Jogy, what did you modify / how?

Comment: this is for a WINDOWS PHONE user control - if that matters

Comment: I tried it with Windows Phone control, and it works too. But check in the project, what is the Build Action for CtrlLocServ? It should be set to "Page". If it is "Content" instead, then this error will happen.

Comment: both are set to 'page'

Comment: I also get this warning:   CS0108: 'CtrlLocServ.InitializeComponent()' hides inherited member 'RML.CtrlBase.InitializeComponent()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: That warning is normal, I get it too in my test example. See explanation here: http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=706&lang=de

Comment: Check the generated code for InitializeComponent() in the derived control, it should contain line like this:             this.LocationConsent_CheckBox = ((System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)(this.FindName("LocationConsent_CheckBox")));

Comment: Jogy - it looks as if the generated file is not being generated correctly ... ?

Comment: @user3174075 I guess so ... try to add another UserControl, then change it so it derives from the base user control and see if it works.

Comment: This is what in the generated file with a new user control :         void System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target) {
            switch (connectionId)
            {
            case 1:
            this.check_box = ((System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)(target));
            return;
            }
            this._contentLoaded = true;
        }       ------>>>> I have not derived the control yet though !

Comment: That is very strange, the generated file should not look like this ... Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CtrlLocationService"
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:RML.Controls"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,10,0">
        <CheckBox 
            x:Name="LocationConsent_CheckBox"
            Content"test"
            Checked="Location_Checked" 
            Unchecked="Location_Unchecked" />

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

to:

```
<src:CtrlBase x:Class="CtrlLocationService"
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:RML.Controls"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,10,0">
        <CheckBox 
            x:Name="LocationConsent_CheckBox"
            Content"test"
            Checked="Location_Checked" 
            Unchecked="Location_Unchecked" />

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>

</src:CtrlBase>
```

If you want to have a base user control for other ones you need to change the base in both code behind and xaml

Comment: Actually, it won't compile at all if the xaml and the code-behind specify different base classes

Comment: well i've seen that he missed that in the xaml code, so it will maybe help someone else

Comment: -1 You can't use a XAML file if you want to extend a control.

Answer (score 0):

still working on this and when I get the working code, I will update

Comment: You can create a UserControl based on another UserControl, you just have to specify the base both in the xaml file and in the code behind

Comment: Jogy - can you take a look at the revised question?

Answer (score 0):

This is working in my simple text example. You can try to access it at https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=b37cc7d5117b9a1b&id=B37CC7D5117B9A1B!27341 and check the differences in the project and in the generated files.

Comment: Got your source code... it compiles ... yay ... just need to dif now